# python: disk-bound task, thread vs process

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I parse a big source code directory (100k files). I traverse every line in every file and do some simple regex matching. I tried threading this task to multiple threads but didn't get any speedup. Only multiprocessing managed to cut the time by 70%. I'm aware of the GIL death grip, but aren't threads supposed to help with IO bound access?

If the disk access is serial, how come several processes finish the job quicker?

Comment: What makes you sure it's disk bound?

Comment: because the only processing I do per line is updating a dict

Comment: Is the regex precompiled?

Comment: yes. I don't think regex matching lines a file takes more time than getting the file handle from the OS.

Comment: Did you try profiling the program? Sounds like you need some hard data to make progress. You can try cProfile: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python "threads" permit independent threads of execution, but typically do not permit concurrency because of the global interpreter lock: only one thread can really be running at a time.  This may be the reason why you only get a speedup with multiple processes, which do not share a global interpreter lock and thus can run concurrently.