# Multithreading optimization

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am processing a large folder with individual images. Each image has multiple channels and needs to be split and saved as a new image per channel. I assumed this would be a candidate problem to tackle with multithreading. However, after timing a conventional for loop and compared it with my multithreading solution, it performed not different at all. Perhaps my code is flawed, or perhaps this problem is not benifited by multithreading? Any insights would be appreciated. My code is below!

```
from nd2reader import ND2Reader
import threading
import os
import re
from PIL import Image
import time
import warnings

inputdir = r'C:\inputdir'
outputdir = r'C:\outputdir'    

def extractDataFromString(input):
    delimiters = ',', '_', '.'
    regexPattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape, delimiters))
    _, _, _, seq, well, time, _ = re.split(regexPattern, input)
    return seq, well, time

def executeSave(file,inputdir,outputdir):
    with ND2Reader(os.path.join(inputdir, file)) as images:
        for i in range(len(images)):
            seq, well, time = extractDataFromString(file)

            image = Image.fromarray(images[i])
            if i == 0:
                c = 'C1'
            elif i == 1:
                c = 'C2'
            elif i == 2:
                c = 'C3'
            elif i == 3:
                c = 'C4'

            image.save(os.path.join(outputdir, seq + '_' + well + '_' + time + '_' + c + '.tif'), format="TIFF")



class FileThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, file, inputdir, outputdir):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.file = file
        self.inputdir = inputdir
        self.outputdir = outputdir

    def run(self):
        self.seq, self.well, self.time = extractDataFromString(self.file)
        executeSave(self.file, self.inputdir, self.outputdir)

#threading
threadlist = [(FileThread(file, inputdir=inputdir,outputdir=outputdir)) for file in os.listdir(inputdir)]

t1 = time.time()

[thread.start() for thread in threadlist]
[thread.join() for thread in threadlist]

t2 = time.time()

#conventional for loop
for file in os.listdir(inputdir):
    executeSave(file,inputdir,outputdir)

t3 = time.time()

print('threading execution took {} seconds'.format(t2-t1))

print('non threading execution took {} seconds'.format(t3-t2))
```

Comment: Note that your code is not runnable (because people don't have the files on your hard disk)

Comment: I am aware. Perhaps any flaws stand out in my syntax that contribute to my 'issue'.

Comment: Could be a GIL problem. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44727134/python-disk-bound-task-thread-vs-process) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10154487/how-to-get-a-faster-speed-when-using-multi-threading-in-python)

Comment: So is multithreading in python some kind of pseudo multithreading?

Comment: Anyways, I applied multiprocessing using Pool and that did lead to a significant time reduction.